# website page losing title

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

i am going mad with this problem now - if u goto http://talll.com and start clicking around on the menu items like news, economics etc., u will find that the page title says "undefined" - i just want to set the page title to some value thats all - HELPPPPPP!!!

Comment: post the relevant code here too.

Comment: @Web Logic - I don't think he really can... the problem is he cant figure out what is erroring.. thats why he provided a link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Line 124 in `script.js`:

```
document.title = $("input[type='hidden'][name='title']").attr("value");
```

Apparently `$("input[type='hidden'][name='title']").attr("value")` is `undefined`.

Comment: Daniel - that worked !!! I set the title to something manually there and that worked!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on line 159:

```
 $("a.ctip").cluetip({
document.title='Talll.com - Daily Links for Finance Professionals';
```

You are passing attributes to that function, you cant just throw the `document.title="blah"` in there. You need to add the `document.title` to an event handler function called when the user clicks on the link.

Comment: both these are my attempts to set the title, both did not help.

whats actually happening i havent understood but the page title becomes undefined. HELP!!

Comment: Webdostraya - THANKS A TON!!!!!!!!!! I changed that and that worked. Can i send you some chocolates ??